# Find common union groups among tuples in a set

Tags: python, set, union-find

I need help to write a function that:

- takes as input set of tuples
- returns the number of tuples that has unique numbers

---

Example 1:

```
# input:
{(0, 1), (3, 4), (0, 0), (1, 1), (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 0)}

# expected output: 3
```

The expected output is 3, because:

- `(3,4)` and `(3,3)` contain common numbers, so this counts as 1
- `(0, 1)`, `(0, 0)`, `(1, 1)`, and `(1, 0)` all count as 1
- `(2, 2)` counts as 1

So, 1+1+1 = 3

---

Example 2:

```
# input:
{(0, 1), (2, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 3), (2, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 3)}

# expected output: 1
```

The expected output is 1, because all tuples are related to other tuples by containing numbers in common.

Comment: This isn't a very precise definition.  What would you do for `(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)`?

Comment: output should be 1 beause all gruop of same numbers

Comment: for this (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4),, (5, 6) output should be 2

Comment: Ok, it sounds like any two pairs with a common value must be in the same group, and in effect you find the smallest partition into groups that doesn't violate that condition.  You could probably solve it with a [union-find algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Comment: When I say "smallest partition", what I mean is the partition with the smallest groups, i.e. the largest number of groups.

Comment: yes ,any two pair that have at leat 1 common number will grouped together with others pairs that answear this condition but this union-find-algorithem looks alot of implementation therse any way to solve it without implement whole data structer for it?

Comment: The union-find algorithm is actually doing more than you need.  Its goal is to allow you to, given an element, find all other elements in that element's group.  But you just need to count the number of groups, which is simpler.  But you still need to do at least some of it.  You will need to create some data structures though, but they can be simple and built directly from pre-existing Python types.

Comment: im solve it im think look at answear

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most efficient algorithm for it, but it is simple and looks nice.

```
from functools import reduce

def unisets(iterables):
  def merge(fsets, fs):
    if not fs: return fsets
    unis = set(filter(fs.intersection, fsets))
    return {reduce(type(fs).union, unis, fs), *fsets-unis}
  return reduce(merge, map(frozenset, iterables), set())

us = unisets({(0,1), (3,4), (0,0), (1,1), (3,3), (2,2), (1,0)})
print(us)       # {frozenset({3, 4}), frozenset({0, 1}), frozenset({2})}
print(len(us))  # 3
```

Features:

- Input can be **any** kind of iterable, whose elements are iterables (any length, mixed types...)
- Output is always a well-behaved set of frozensets.

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me
but check it maby there edge cases
how this solution?

```
def count_groups(marked):
    temp = set(marked)
    save = set()
    for pair in temp:
        if pair[1] in save or pair[0] in save:
            marked.remove(pair)
        else:
            save.add(pair[1])
            save.add(pair[0])
    return len(marked)
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8o4G.png)

Comment: This code gives wrong results. For example, for `input={(0,1), (2,2), (4,3), (2,0)}`, it gives `3` (groups `0,1`, `2,2`, `4,3`), while the correct answer should be `2` (groups `0,1,2`, `4,3`).

Comment: This doesn't look at all close.  Also, it's destructively modifying `marked`, which you probably don't want to do.  Make a copy first if you want to make changes.